# During compilation QMainWindow is unable to be found

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt4, cmake

I am attempting to compile cutecash (a qt project) and having a bit of trouble. I am just doing the standard:

```
cmake .
make
```

However, I am getting errors about not being able to find QMainWindow and QString among other things. Here is the error:

http://pastebin.com/GGHTXE4N

```
In file included from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/fpo/ViewletView.hpp:14:0,
                 from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/fpo/FPO.hpp:4,
                 from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/fpo/moc_FPO.cxx:9:
/home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/mainwindow.hpp:26:23: fatal error: QMainWindow: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/moc_RecentFileMenu.cxx:15:2: error: #error "This file was generated using the moc from 5.0.1. It"
/home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/moc_RecentFileMenu.cxx:16:2: error: #error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
/home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/moc_RecentFileMenu.cxx:17:2: error: #error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
In file included from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/AccountItemModel.hpp:28:0,
                 from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/dashboard.hpp:34,
                 from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/moc_dashboard.cxx:9:
/home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/QofEventWrapper.hpp:37:19: fatal error: QString: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/SplitListModel.hpp:29:0,
                 from /home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/moc_SplitListModel.cxx:9:
/home/username/code/gnucash/src/gnc/QofEventWrapper.hpp:37:19: fatal error: QString: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Something that seems fairly significant:

```
error: #error "This file was generated using the moc from 5.0.1. It"
error: #error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
error: #error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
```

So whenever I attempt to install `qt5-default` (on ubuntu) I must remove `qt4-default`. If I attempt to compile now, I get the same issues with being unable to fin QMainWindow and a few other pieces (such as QAbstractItemDelegate).

I also receive this warning:

```
#error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC or -fPIE."
```

Along with a few new errors which seem like they happen due to being unable to find items. I am on ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I guess QMainWindow class was moved to QtWidgets module in Qt5.

Comment: true. Try adding +widgets to .pro file or try using Qt4.8

Comment: Actually no .pro exists, everything is setup to work via cmake. And I'm using 4.8.4

Comment: I would clear your cmake cache and reconfigure and regenerate making sure that cmake finds Qt-4.8.4 instead of Qt5.

Comment: Just in case, you would like to build cutecash with Qt 4 or 5? Also, please use cmake .. (i.e. shadow build) because it is easier to clean up stray files like here...

Comment: @SebastianLange: that would not explain QString though. Also, if I understand correctly, the OP would like to build it with Qt 4. The question is also tagged like that.

Comment: What a fail from them... --   package 'guile-1.8>=1.8.0' not found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:89 (MESSAGE):
  Guile was not found, but is required.  Please set PKG_CONFIG_PATH so that
  guile-1.8.pc is found. We have 2.0 on Archlinux, so ...

Comment: @LaszloPapp Correct, Qt 4

Comment: @jett: have you tried the steps I provided? Also, paste more by using make VERBOSE=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps that work for me:

- svn checkout http://svn.gnucash.org/repo/gnucash/trunk
- mkdir -p trunk/build
- cd trunk/build
- cmake ..
- make